# "Дівочка" чи "дівчинка"?

Tags: вибір-слова

Чи доречне вживання слова «дівочка», коли йде мова про дівчинку-підлітка? Дана форма поширена на теренах Волинської області. Моя бабуся завжди вживала це слово, коли намагалась говорити про дівчинку від 12-13 до 16. Це звучало так: "Вона вже дівочка". Більше такого я не зустрічала. Тому й цікавлюсь чи є доречною така назва.

Comment: **Comments removed**. Друзі, нагадую, що коментарі до запитання існують для уточнення запитання з метою зробити **запитання** кращим. Chit-chatting і відповіді, у тому числі часткові — офф-топік.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зокрема в СУМ зазначено

> ***[Дівочка](http://sum.in.ua/s/divochka)***  и, жін. Зменш.-пестл. до дівка 1. Та малая нічка
>   Петрівочка, Та не виспалася Наша дівочка (Українські народні ліричні
>   пісні, 1958, 89); З дитини отака дівочка виросла (Андрій Головко, I,
>   1957, 245);  * У порівняннях. — Молодиця, як калина, як яблучко, як
>   дівочка (Марко Вовчок, I, 1955, 14).

Також ***"Дівочка"*** зустрічається в ["Словники України on-line"](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/)

В ["Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов)"](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)  вказано, що саме дане слово вживається до дівчат-підлітків:

> **Де́вочка-подросток** – ***ді́вочка***, пі́ддівок (р. -вка, м. р.), (шутл.)
>   дівчу́к (м. р.). [Під одніє́ю ха́тою сиді́ла ку́пка не дівча́т, а ще
>   пі́ддівків – ро́ків тринацятьо́х або чотирнацятьо́х (Грінч.)].

Тому, на мою думку, така назва є доречною.